How to remove colored boxes from cases environment in beamer
When used in beamer, the following code draws these awful looking boxes over the cases. How can I remove these so it looks normal?
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={table,dvipsnames},t]{beamer}
\usetheme{UCBerkeley}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, graphicx, subfigure}
\usepackage{braket}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
T_{ij} = \begin{cases}
    1/\deg(v_j), &\text{if}\ (v_j,v_i) \in E\\
    0, &\text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



If what you're using is the same as the UCBerkeley beamer theme on Overleaf, then the colored rows in cases env is caused by \rowcolors{2}{BerkeleyTableBlue1}{BerkeleyTableBlue2} set by that theme. Adding \hiderowcolors at the very beginning of cases env is one of the solutions. I'm sure others will provide more automatic ways.

You're a hero, thanks!

Unrelated to your problem, but you don't need amssymb, amsmath, graphicx. Beamer loads these packages for you.

If what you're using is the same as the UC Berkeley beamer theme on Overleaf, then the colored rows in cases env is caused by
\rowcolors{2}{BerkeleyTableBlue1}{BerkeleyTableBlue2}

set by that Beamer theme (beamerthemeUCBerkeley.sty).
Following example adds \AddToHook{env/cases/begin}{\rowcolors{2}{}{}} to cancel global \rowcolors setting at the beginning of every cases environment.
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={table,dvipsnames},t]{beamer}
\usetheme{UCBerkeley}
\usepackage{tikz}
% \usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, graphicx}
\usepackage{braket}

% cancel global \rowcolors setting for all "cases" environment
% equivalent to \AtBeginEnvironment{cases}{\rowcolors{2}{}{}}
\AddToHook{env/cases/begin}{\rowcolors{2}{}{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{align*}
T_{ij} = \begin{cases}
    1/\deg(v_j), &\text{if}\ (v_j,v_i) \in E\\
    0, &\text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


